# Parse single line values from a text file in Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to parse a text file with a single line divided in values in Android? An example of file i would like to parse could be:

```
100,102,106,109,110
```

And the solution I'm looking for would be something like

```
Log.d(TAG, "value 1" + theFirstValue);    
Log.d(TAG, "value 2" + theSecondValue);

//etc...
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `String.split()` method.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard, "path/to/the/file");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {       
    String[] split = line.split(","); 
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      Log.d(TAG, "value " + i + ": " + split[i]);
    }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Hello!!! as for vipul mittal reply i need to retrieve the values from a text file located in Android! this files contains 6 values different from device to device!

Comment: Hello, i have edited the answer. Also make sure you have the required permissions to read files.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="100,102,106,109,110";
String[] values=s.split(",");

for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
     int v=Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
     Log.d(TAG, "value "+i +": "+ v);   
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply! i need to retrieve the values from a text file! this file is always present in Android but with different values from device to device! :)